# What's the purpose of const parameters in a constructor?

Tags: c++

This is a program that uses classes, together with parameter constructors.

```
#include <string>

class Ball {

private:
    std:: string m_color;
    double m_radius;
public:

    Ball(const std::string& color, double radius)
    {
        m_color = color;
        m_radius = radius;
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "color: " << m_color << std::endl;
        std::cout << "radius: " << m_radius;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Ball blueTwenty{ "blue", 20.0 };
    blueTwenty.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Why do we have to add `const` before our first parameter? I see that the double-type parameter doesn't need one. Also, why do we need the first address of the parameter (I guess this is the reason for including `&`)? Could anyone explain the logic behind?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: The copy operator `std::string::operator=` expects a `const std::string&` which could otherwise be just used as a simple `std::string` if the string were to be modified anywhere inside the scope of constructor. This is not considered to be necessary but is a good habit to get into.

Comment: "why do we need the first address of the parameter" - Remember that C++ is a *context sensitive* language. `&` means different things in different contexts. It doesn't always mean "address of", here it means "reference" - it can also mean "bitwise and" in other contexts.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that it doesn't need one, but that the `const` was omitted. Changing `radius` won't impact the caller, but `color`, as a reference, *could*. Technically they should both be `const` unless they need to be modified.

`const` just says "I promise not to modify this argument" which the compiler can interpret a number of ways, including making optimizations in the code based on that.

It also avoids inadvertent mutation of arguments which can cause unpredictable side-effects.